# Angular2 trying to import Orizens Infinite scroll, getting error TS2307 cannot find '@angular/core'

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-modules

I have installed angular 2 using the cookbook from angular2's official website, but i a facing a problem when i try to import external modules.
I have different npm packages, but with them all i get the error in the title:

> cannot find module 'angular2/core'.

i have installed the package with the npm install function:

> npm install angular2-infinite-scroll --save

am i doing somthing wrong? or do i need to change some configuration somewhere?
Here is a link to the package i try to install:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-infinite-scroll

Here are my tsconfig file:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": [
        "app/Components/"
      ],
      "models/*": [
        "app/Models/"
      ],
      "service/*": [
        "app/Services/"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

when i look at the files that thorws an error i can see that they are located in somthing called TypeScript Virtual Projects, but i cannot see them in the solution explorer. My tsconfig, and typings.json is in the project root folder, mean while my main, app.module and app.component is in the app root folder.